# D3 force directed layout - changing node color and its links color on button click

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, force-layout

I'm little bit lost again and I need your help with my "fungraph" in D3. I wanna to color all nodes with same given class "person" and also their links with a click of the button.

I've managed to get nodes colored up in red color but I have issues with links.

I've tried to use simplified version of fade function which I'm using for mouseover on my nodes. I've first created on click function for button:

```
$(".btn_person").on("click",function(){

        d3.selectAll(".person").select('circle')
                    .transition()
                    .duration(500)
                    .attr("style", "fill:red; stroke:red; stroke-width: 2px;" )
                    .call(fadeAll(.4,"red"));


 });
```

and created fadeAll function which I'm calling as you see:

```
 function fadeAll(opacity,color) {

        return function(d) {


            link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity;
                })   
                .style("stroke", function(o) {
                    return o.source === d || o.target === d ? color : "#000" ;
                });
            };

        }
```

But it does not work as I expected. I get no errors but links from the colored nodes does not get colored to red and all links does get opacity of 0.4 and I do not why? Am I calling the function in the wrong way?

You can see my situation, and test the issue when you click on button "person" on following link: http://jsfiddle.net/9rSM6/

The problematic code is at end of JavaScript code.

Any help or advice is welcome.

Comment: Your jsfiddle displays only a button and nothing else; is this the way you wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost there -- `d` is a D3 selection, so you cannot compare elements to it directly. Rather, you need to extract the elements in the selection and then check whether `.source` or `.target` is in this array:

```
var e = [];
d.each(function(a, i) { e[i] = a; });

link.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {
    return e.indexOf(o.source) != -1 || e.indexOf(o.target) != -1 ? 1 : opacity;
  })   
  .style("stroke", function(o) {
    return e.indexOf(o.source) != -1 || e.indexOf(o.target) != -1 ? color : "#000" ;
  });
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/9rSM6/1/).

Comment: aa that is the catch! Great man thank you a lot. I'm trying to do same for nodes, if they are connected leave opacity at one all other fade them... I'll ask a question again if I get stuck :)

Comment: Could you help a little bit further? I'm stuck with those nodes, I do not know why every nodes but the last three are getting opacity of 0.4.. I've compared it with: node.style("stroke-opacity", function(o) {

             e.forEach(function(a){
          thisOpacity = isConnected(a, o) ? 1 : opacity;
                 });
                 this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
                   return thisOpacity;
            });. Here is a link: http://jsfiddle.net/rd3Uv/ or maybe I open a new question? It is down on 507 line

Comment: That was not my intention, I wanted that those nodes which are coloured and neighbour nodes wich are connected with their links does not get faded out, just ones that do not have anything with them are faded out... I started something but it just applies to first occurence as you see in above link

Comment: I don't really understand what you want. What do you want to fade out?

Comment: I want to fade out those nodes that do not turn red and that bigger ones which are not connected to those red wit "person" class

Comment: It is probably some wrong logic from my side because I succeeded in one occurence, as you can test on my last link I posted. that forEach loop needs be configured maybe in other way...

Comment: Yea, exactly... You are golden man, apart from my lack of knowledge on d3 I'm still a lot nooby about javascript... thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "d" of the returned function is not the same like the id of the node. Furthermore, the source and target objects can not be compared against other objects that were used as keys. IMO objects should not be used as keys.

The following code worked for me [(see complete code)](https://github.com/nise/moduleBase/blob/master/public/static/views/analysis_course_similarity.ejs):

```
function fadeAll(opacity,color) { 
            return function(ds) { 
                var selected = Number(d3.select(this).attr('id')); 
                link
                    .style("stroke-opacity", function(o) { 
                        return o.source.id === selected || o.target.id === selected ? 1 : 0.1;
                    })   
                    .style("stroke", function(o) {
                        return o.source.id === selected || o.target.id === selected ? "#000" : "#ddd" ;
                    })
                    ;
            }
        }
```